# Doctrine ODM saving big number

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, integer

This might be a stupid question, but I'm struggling to save a big number in mongoDB document.

Basically, I want to save a number that can be bigger than the max int value. Thus, I declared my document field as a `@Field(type="float")`.

Now the problem is that saving the number result in an error. I also tried simply using `@Integer` but the number was reduced to **2147483647** (which is the max int value for 32 bits system).

So I tried a last solution, saving my number in a string. This works fine (at least it appears to be correct in the database), but returning the document and doing a `echo $number` gives me back **2147483647**.

Anybody has a fix to this ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it not returning cached value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last things first: The value is being displayed as the max-int value because PHP is seeing it as numeric. You can see more about this process [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

The mongodb extension itself does support 64-bit integers on 32-bit systems using [MongoInt64](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoint64.php), but the Doctrine ODM doesn't handle 32- or 64-bit integers differently when hydrating back from MongoDB, so you'll never see that 64-bit value come back as a `MongoInt64` class, even if PHP could support it -- which it can't :)

SO, I'd say your options are either force the value to a string (`echo (String) $number;`), or try and troubleshoot why you are getting an error attempting to save the value as a float. There are precision [issues](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) with floats in php that may make it untenable to store the number that way regardless.

Hope this helps!